# Identify CPU usage by thread or service

Tags: windows-vista, performance, cpu-usage

How can I analyze the CPU usage that is associated with a Windows thread or service? Sometimes my dual processor CPU will show 49% CPU usage for task SVCHOST - for example, yesterday it used 49% for over three hours. Now it's doing it again today.

Using Task Manager, if you right-click on the task and select 'Go To Service(s)' it will identify 18 services, but no detail for each. I have tried 'Process Explorer v16.2', but still no breakdown.

- Scanned for Malware, SpyBot, Virus = all clean.
- Looked at all of the system log's - nothing stood out.
- Boot in Safe Mode, problem seems to go away.
- Tried to install Windows SDK for WinDbg, but it fails with    error.
- I am running Windows Vista (I can actually feel the groan - it is so
  loud! Long story, but my PC really does run as great as the day I
  bought it.)

New Info: I decided to go down the list of services running under the SVCHOST task and stop each service until either CPU decreased, or I crashed windows. When I stopped 'Windows Update', CPU went to normal.

After hours of searching for known issues, and attempting to apply solutions, the problem persisted. For the short term, I decided to set Windows Update to 'Manual Start' DO NOT DO THAT UNLESS YOU UNDERSTAND THE RISKS!!!

My original need was to be able to identify the service using the high CPU by using some type of monitor. Although I got around that need, I would still like to know if such a tool exists.

Comment: That sounds like your antivirus software is running a scan. You can see the services that are running under the particular SVCHOST, but I'm not familiar with a way to see which specific service is running hot. But, if you've got AV running under that service, it's a likely cause.

Comment: I decided to take a gamble, so went to services list for that SVCHost, then started at the top and 'stopped' the service(s). When I got to the 2nd service, it was 'Windows Update', and when I stopped it, bingo! CPU back to normal.  I am currently googling for a solution... found a couple Microsoft hot fixes that are very old, but need to keep looking. I agree with you regarding antivirus, but had halted that yesterday. Thank you very much for your reply!!

Comment: If you know which updates you're missing, you may be able to download them manually from https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/

Comment: Thank you @music2myear   After several hours of research and attempting to apply recommended solutions, no luck. For the short term I disabled Windows Update (I know!) Longer term, I dread replacing the PC. Yes, it is 10 years old, but it runs as fast today as when it was new - and I sometimes have 10 or 12 apps active. Thanks again!

Comment: Perhaps the computer just needs refreshing. Vista can still benefit from a reinstall from time to time, but definitely make sure you've thoroughly checked out the Windows Update slowness solutions if you haven't already.

Comment: Yes, I have flat-lined Vista 3 or 4 times in the 10 years (either by stupidity, or by design). I am now attempting WSUSoffline as mentioned in the answer in the link @magicandre1981 suggested.

Comment: ok, but support for Vista officially ends next month. so in april the last updates are released. I assume that WSUSoffline now drops vista as option. but because Vista is the same codebase as Server 2008 (NOT 2008 R2), you can install the 2008 updates starting in may 2017

Comment: Uodate re WSUSoffline: latest version DOES work with Vista (my bad); download and installed 31 updates. Since this thread has now taken a turn from 'how to identify cpu by service' to Vista updates, I think I will close it. I really appreciate the great feedback you have provided!

Comment: yes, for now it works. But I guess in may it will fail. so just a warning. try to use the 2008 server updates. here go to MS pages and download all updates for each patchday on your own and install them via double click on MSU